# Error on Android Media player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, illegalstateexception

Currently I am working on a music Player. Please help me out with these errors

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button playb,pauseb,stopb;

    SeekBar seeker;
    Handler seekhandler;
    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        player=new MediaPlayer();//.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.spaceman);

        //Interface between code and xml
        playb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        stopb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
        pauseb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.pause_button);
        seeker=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);


        try {
            player.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),(CharSequence) e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
        //Code for Play Button
        playb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                player.stop();
                player.reset();
                seeker.setProgress(0);
                try {
                    player.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence) e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                player.start();
                seeker.setMax(player.getDuration());
            }
        });


        //Code for Pause button
        pauseb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            player.pause();
            }
        });

        //code for Stop button
        stopb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

             player.reset();
            }
        });


        //Code for seekbar change listner
        seeker.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        Runnable runnable =new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                seeker.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());
                seekhandler.postDelayed(this,1000);

            }
        };
    }
}
```

Errors:

> 09-19 20:16:15.342 25242-25242/main.deviac.com.seekbar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                            Process: main.deviac.com.seekbar, PID: 25242
>                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{main.deviac.com.seekbar/main.deviac.com.seekbar.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2535)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                             **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException**
>                                                                                at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
>                                                                                at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1158)
>                                                                                at main.deviac.com.seekbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
>                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285)
>                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2535) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497) 
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>   09-19 20:16:15.344 25242-25242/main.deviac.com.seekbar D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
>   09-19 20:16:28.590 25409-25409/main.deviac.com.seekbar W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/main.deviac.com.seekbar-2/lib/arm64
>   09-19 20:16:28.669 25409-25409/main.deviac.com.seekbar W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/main.deviac.com.seekbar-2/lib/arm64

I have kept mp3 file(spaceman) in raw folder which resides in res directory

Comment: Solved your problem ? @Atharva Muley

Comment: No,its still giving the same error.I  tried rebuilding the project but all was in vain !. Also I m totally new to android programming@Vinoth Vino

Comment: Have you tried implementing the code which I answered here @Atharva Muley

Comment: Yes I tried  create method , haven't tried another @Vinoth Vino

Comment: Try setDataSource method @Atharva Muley

Comment: Do you have any sample code ,which will work as a tutorial?,or pls suggest any good website@Vinoth Vino

Comment: Yeah I'll try setDataSource method ,and will get back to you@Vinoth Vino

Comment: Have you tried setDataSource method ? Give it a try @Atharva Muley

Comment: I just updated my answer. Check it out @Atharva Muley

Comment: So now I will have to move my mp3 file from raw folder to Music Directory ryt?@Vinoth Vino

Comment: Can you please upload a screenshot of your code snippet ? Just edit your question and attach the screenshot

Comment: Nope...You can do in both ways @Atharva Muley

Comment: As being an engineering student I'm bit busy today ,I'll get back to you in a day or two!

Comment: If my answer helps you then thank me by accepting and upvoting my answer. I hope my answer would help you for sure. Happy Coding... @Atharva Muley

Comment: Yeah I'll get back to you @Vinoth Vino

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Android's media player, or as I call it, "state-based hell".

Your original error was caused by preparing the media player, you don't prepare the media player if you play audio files locally, as the create() method (if you use this method to create the media player) automatically prepares. There were additional media player state-based errors but the code below should fix them.

Disregarding the seekbar code right now (I would get this basic play, pause, and stop code working before adding in the seekbar functionality), your code for the play, pause, and stop buttons should be like this:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button playb, pauseb, stopb;

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Interface between code and xml
        playb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        stopb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
        pauseb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause_button);

        //Code for Play Button
        playb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.file_to_play.mp3);                
                mediaPlayer.start();

            }
        });


        //Code for Pause button
        pauseb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }

            }
        });

        //code for Stop button
        stopb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Agree, this mediaplayer of Android contains some very bad coding, in particular, it has a total incapacity to handle errors that take place between Java and Native. And it puts things in cache that it does not clear up when you release the player. You are then stuck until you restart the app and clear cache. Here is one error message that is typical, the player has entered a state it does not understand: E/MediaPlayer: Unknown message type 10000, causing pauses in sound as the player repeatedly tries to recoup, but is unable to. A scandal.

Answer (score 0):

You've to add **file path** to your media player. Just call a static method `create` in your media player class

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yoursongfile);
```

or invoke the `setDataSource` method

```
player.setDataSource("/sdcard/Music/songfile.mp3");//Path of your song location
```

or you can also access the resource like this below

`player.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.package.name/raw/songfile"));`

[See this doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)